# Is the frequency accuracy of this MAX7373 oscillator within tolerance?

Tags: oscillator, mems

I'm currently using a Maximum Integrated MAX7375 MEMS 8MHz oscillator (http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/maxim-integrated/MAX7375AXR805-T/MAX7375AXR805-TCT-ND/4967873) as a clock source for a microcontroller project.

While doing some tests on the microcontroller, I noticed that the internal time of the microcontroller was going a little faster than the real world time. For example, when I would set an alarm on the microcontroller for 30 minutes, it would be go off after 29:44. When I would set it for 1 hour, it would go off at 59:28.

I then attempted another timing method within the microcontroller and had the same results. I decided that my 8MHz clock must be going a little faster than 8MHz. I then took the oscillator to the oscilloscope and was able to confirm that my clock was operating at 8.09MHz.

So my question: is this performance typical, or in range for this oscillator? I notice that the data sheet specs the oscillator as 8.00MHz, which seems to suggest that my oscillator is operating at the worst possible rate for its tolerance.

Furthermore, why exactly would this oscillator be performing so poorly? I thought MEMS oscillators were often considered superior than cap/crystal resonators? Thoughts?

Comment: Well, have you like, looked up exactly that information in their datasheet?

Comment: The datasheet shows an accuracy spec of 2%. So anything between about 7.84MHz and 8.16MHz is within spec. This device isn't particularly suitable for precision timekeeping.

Comment: @PlasmaHH All it states is 8.00MHz, but does that mean the last significant digit can vary? So 8.09MHz would still considered meet tolerance? Furthermore, the datasheet lists other chips in the family at 4.19MHz. I'm just trying to figure out if the last digit is free to vary.

Comment: @Teague: maybe read it again? I have the feeling that it talks about 2% initial accuracy somewhere...

Comment: ... and if your supply voltage isn't a nice stable 3.0V, the frequency could vary even more.

Comment: @brhans I assumed 2% initial accuracy was the accuracy at startup before reaching a steadystate. I guess I misinterpreted that.

Comment: 59:28 = 3568 seconds, 1 hour is 3600 seconds so that's 0.89 % faster. Well within that 2% spec. So nothing unexpected here. If you want more accurate timing: us a **crystal**, not a resonator.

Comment: @Teague: intial accuracy is the accuracy that it is delivered with. It can get even worse over time.

Comment: "Initial Accuracy" mean before it drifts even further off due to temperature & aging ...

Comment: And it will vary over temperature as well and over time (due to aging).

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thanks for this, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: When reading a datasheet, always remember that it was drawn up by the *marketing* dept. There *will* be some "specmanship" involved - particularly for any number related to accuracy/performance/etc. The most obvious specs shown will be the *best case* and you're going to have to dig and add up to get a realistic number.

Comment: I don't know how their construction differs from this part, but SiTime has MEMS oscillators that achieve better than 1E-6 accuracy, with low phase noise and good vibration immunity as well - overall better than crystals and even TCXOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is behind the characteristics:

[image]

So, this part has a minimum frequency of 8 x 0.96 = 7.68MHz and a maximum frequency of 8 x 1.04 = 8.32MHz. You measured 8.09MHz which is in guaranteed range.